# What is the advantage of using Visual Studio 2008 on Xp 64bit

Tags: visual-studio-2008, 32bit-64bit

Currently my development environment is Windows Xp 32 bit and Visual studio 2008 with SP1.

I have 2 GB of RAM and C2D 2.4 GHz processor.

What are the advantages if i install Xp 64 bit?? Whereas the application which i am developing is intended to run on Xp 64 bit machine with 32GB of memory

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Visual Studio is not a relevant factor in your decision to migrate to a 64-bit version of Windows. Search [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/) for questions that have already been asked and answered regarding the *general* benefits of using 64-bit editions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no advantage except that your development OS would then be the same as the target production OS. This may aid in testing/debugging on your own machine (assuming that is what you do.)

In general the advantages of a 64 bit OS are mainly the ability to address more RAM, but your machine only have 2GB anyway.
I suppose you would also get IIS 6.0 rather than 5.1 as in XP32, if that matters.
However, XP 64 bit is not very highly regarded at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on my "XP 64 bit is not very highly regarded at all"? By whom? For what reasons?

Comment: Becuase it is not often used and is quite poorly supported. eg. quite hard to get drivers for, no SP3, bad software support.

Comment: And there's no 64-bit build of Visual Studio, so you won't get any advantage on the development side.

Comment: @Ciaran: With that logic, why should *any* developer run a 64-bit version of Windows? I migrated a long time ago, and I'm glad I did. The lack of a 64-bit version of VS is not a handicap, nor does it seem to be to be a relevant concern.

Comment: @Cody: You're right - I wasn't quite clear. I didn't mean that there's no point in developing on 64-bit, just that VS itself wouldn't take advantage of the 64-bit features. In fact I would recommend that Mohsan develop on 64-bit because that's his target architecture.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Ciaran is right, the question is about VS not Windows 64 bits. While XP or whatever OS might benefit from going 64bit, VS as such will not.

Comment: @Johann: That's plainly incorrect. The question is about migrating to a 64-bit version of Windows. There *is* no 64-bit version of Visual Studio, and one is not being developed because it doesn't provide any advantages at this time. That doesn't mean there are no significant advantages for a developer migrating to a 64-bit version of Windows. I don't know about you, but I frequently run more than one application on my computer at a time.

Comment: I think we can all agree that if you have >2 GB of system RAM then there's definitely a benefit to moving to a 64 bit OS (preferably Win7 instead of XP64) even if MS it typically shortsighted and VS is still a 32 bit process.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Sorry I was not very clear, my point was (as the title says) that VS does not benefit from a 64bit OS. I totally agree with you on everything else.